# Turning Android Phone Into A Server

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct, file-sharing

I am building an android app that turns the phone into a server allowing the easy transfer of files between phone and a computer with WIFI speed. WIFI direct is the easier route to go using createGroup(). However, I cannot seem to control the name of the WIFI as it shows on the computer and it self generates the password as well. How can I change the WIFI name and either remove or reset the password as well?
OnePlus does something similar using FileDash.

Answer (score 1):

Wifi Direct is not the easier route to go. Go for `ServerSocket`. It will help you serve things even when you are connected to wifi and other devices in the same network will be able to connect to your device using `Socket`.

It will also work for Java Desktop apps.

Server side:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4576); // or any port
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

Client side:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(IP_OF_SERVER, 4576);
```

After that, use `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` to share files.

Comment: Thought of that, however, it is my understanding that WIFI direct has faster file transfer. This will become important when transferring heavier files like MP3.

Comment: If you use Wifi Hotspot instead of connecting to external router, you will get the speed of Wifi Direct.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to network programming. Not sure what you mean. I assumed the sockets connected directly using ports and the server IP. How does either a Hotspot or router affect it?

Comment: Hey, not sure if you're still there. But from further research. Is the idea that I launch the hotspot on the device, connect the pc, and use the IP address from the phone connection as my socket connection to get the required speeds?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Also regarding previous question, most of the routers are slower than hotspot because router needs to handle both upstream to destination and downstream from source, while when using hotspot, one device will handle upstream and another will handle downstream only. 
Check this very simple code for sharing messages between two android devices: https://github.com/nabinbhandari/android-socket-messaging